# How to dodge pointrange ggplots on two levels?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I would like to make a point range plot where points of groups are not stacked on each other. The plot should look like this:[image]:

My best attempt to do the dodging is to use a vector in dodge argument:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    Temp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "20"), class = "factor"), Rep = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Meas = c(3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), SD = c(2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Treatment", 
"Temp", "Rep", "Meas", "SD"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Treatment, y = Meas, ymin = Meas - SD/2, ymax = Meas + SD/2)) +
geom_linerange(aes(color = Temp), position=position_dodge(width=c(0.6,0.4)), size = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
geom_point(aes(color = Temp, shape = Temp), position=position_dodge(width=c(0.6,0.4)), size = 3) +
theme_bw()
```

Which leads to a plot shown below. However, all of the points are not dodged and I have to move the dots and error bars in Illustrator to get a plot show above. **Is there a way to use dodge argument in `ggplot2` on two levels?**
[image]

Comment: +1!Why the downvote here!!

Comment: Interesting question, you get alittle better results by specifying `Rep` as a grouping variable, `ggplot(dat, aes(x = Treatment, y = Meas, ymin = Meas - SD/2, ymax = Meas + SD/2, group = Rep))`, but still not quite optimal. Also you can simplify the call by using `geom_pointrange`, e.g. `geom_pointrange(aes(color = Temp, shape = Temp), position=position_dodge(width=c(0.6,0.4)), size = 1, alpha = 0.7)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thinking logically, `position_dodge` is more suitable for bars. It does work with `lineranges` on one factor level, however on the second level it's hard to define the minimum distance between the lines. Though you can make a numerical distinction between factors and then add proper position for labels.

```
dat1<-cbind(dat,aux=rep(1,length(dat[,1]))) 
dat1<-within(dat1, {aux = unlist(by(aux,Treatment,cumsum))})
dat1$aux<-dat1$aux+as.numeric(dat1$Treatment)*10
ggplot(dat1, aes( x=aux, y = Meas, ymin = Meas - SD/2, ymax = Meas + SD/2)) +
geom_linerange(aes(color = Temp), size = 1, alpha = 0.5) +geom_point(aes(color = Temp, shape = Temp))+
scale_x_continuous("Treatment",breaks=c(13.5,23.5), labels=c("A","B")) + # here you define coordinates for A and B 
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I think, you can use `position_dodge` for `lineranges` as well. The point is that it'll dodge values (grouped by `colour`) by `Treatment` and the OP needs dodge within that as well. That is, if there were only 1 value each for `Temp=10` and `Temp=20`, `dodge` would work just fine.

Comment: There's no problem of using dodge for factor `Temp`. The problem is that all `lineranges` are merged together. To prevent this I used the different factor for each observation. When we're putting dodge on factor `Treatment` we set some spacing according to X coordinate of A and B on the both sides. Each line also have the exact X coordinate however you can't do dodge on second factor, even grouping with different factor for every line wont help.

Comment: yes, i get that. I was just writing about your first and second lines.

Answer (score 2):

This will not solve the problem with `position_dodge()` but will be workaround for this problem.

Added new variable `x` to your original data frame. It contains `x` coordinates for points/lineranges. Values in data frame should be in order you want to plot them.

```
dat$x<-c(0.85,0.9,0.95,1.05,1.1,1.15,1.85,1.9,1.95,2.05,2.1,2.15)
```

Now use this new variable as `x` values and with `scale_x_continuos()` set breaks and labels to get `A` and `B` on scale.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = Meas, ymin = Meas - SD/2, ymax = Meas + SD/2)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(color = Temp), size = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Temp, shape = Temp), size = 3) +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_continuous("Treatment",breaks=c(1,2),labels=c("A","B"),limits=c(0.5,2.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Way overdue but should someone be looking for an answer like I was, a colleague showed me to make a group aesthetic with an interaction like so:

```
dat <- structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                              2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
                      Temp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                         2L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "20"), class = "factor"), Rep = c(1L, 
                                                                                                     2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Meas = c(3L, 
                                                                                                                                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), SD = c(2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Treatment", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Temp", "Rep", "Meas", "SD"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Treatment, y = Meas, ymin = Meas - SD/2, ymax = Meas + SD/2)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(color = Temp, group = interaction(Rep, Temp)), position=position_dodge(width=c(0.6)), size = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Temp, shape = Temp, group = interaction(Rep, Temp)), position=position_dodge(width=c(0.6)), size = 3) +
  theme_bw()
```