# Add space or break between every second label on x-axis ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis-labels

How can I add a space or break between every second label on the x-axis in ggplot, to introduce some distance between each set of platforms (FB, IG, and TW)?

If I try adding blank rows to the dataframe, ggplot drops them (even after adding drop=FALSE to scale_x_discrete).

I also do not want to fix this by saving the figure larger (because there are more variables than what I include here).

Here is the code:

```
Platform <- c("FB Left-wing", "FB Right-wing",
              "IG Left-wing", "IG Right-wing",
              "TW Left-wing", "TW Right-wing")

Ideology <- c("Left", "Right", "Left", "Right","Left", "Right")

CI_low <- c(1.049, 0.906, 1.212, 0.989, 1.122, 1.080)
CI_high <- c(1.299, 1.144, 1.483, 1.235, 1.362, 1.335)
CI_mid <- c(1.167, 1.018, 1.340, 1.105, 1.236, 1.201)

dat_figure <- data.frame(Platform, Ideology, CI_low, CI_high, CI_mid)

figure <- ggplot(dat_figure, aes(x = Platform, y = CI_mid, colour = Ideology)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = CI_low, ymax = CI_high)) + 
  ylim(0, 4) + 
  ylab("Odds Ratio") + 
  xlab("Platform and Ideology") + 
  theme_bw() 

figure
```

And the output:

[image: Figure]

I would like to add a space between 'FB Right-wing and IG Left-wing', and 'IG Right-wing and TW Left-wing'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solution isn't exactly what you asked for, but I think it is one way to visualize the structure of data:

```
library(ggplot2)

Platform <- c("FB Left-wing", "FB Right-wing",
              "IG Left-wing", "IG Right-wing",
              "TW Left-wing", "TW Right-wing")

Party <- c("FB", "FB", "IG", "IG", "TW", "TW")
  
Ideology <- c("Left", "Right", "Left", "Right","Left", "Right")

CI_low <- c(1.049, 0.906, 1.212, 0.989, 1.122, 1.080)
CI_high <- c(1.299, 1.144, 1.483, 1.235, 1.362, 1.335)
CI_mid <- c(1.167, 1.018, 1.340, 1.105, 1.236, 1.201)

dat_figure <- data.frame(Platform, Party, Ideology, CI_low, CI_high, CI_mid)

ggplot(dat_figure, aes(x = Party, y = CI_mid, colour = Ideology)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = CI_low, ymax = CI_high), position = position_dodge(0.5)) + 
  ylim(0, 4) + 
  ylab("Odds Ratio") + 
  xlab("Platform and Ideology") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is a neat solution that helps readability. Appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome! Here's a similar question that may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472158/how-to-dodge-pointrange-ggplots-on-two-levels

Answer (score 1):

One common way to display categorical data is to facet it. Here the `media` column is created for the facet.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat_figure <- dat_figure %>% mutate(media = sub("\\s.*", "", Platform))

ggplot(dat_figure, aes(x = Platform, y = CI_mid, colour = Ideology)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = CI_low, ymax = CI_high)) + 
  ylim(0, 4) + 
  ylab("Odds Ratio") + 
  xlab("Platform and Ideology") + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ media, scale = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this but it might get messy with additional platforms. I'll give it a shot.